# xUnit.net - How a custom tests runner can give arguments to the unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

Base on [this excellent sample](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestRunner/Program.cs)

I'm able to create a [custom Test Runner](https://gist.github.com/duongphuhiep/410e32a2b4710656900e88a24190b3bb) to execute any external tests dlls. Something like:

```
testReport = MyTestRunner.Run(@"External_Unit_Test.dll");
```

`MyTestRunner` wants to give some arguments / configurations to `External_Unit_Test.dll` before its run. How to achieve that?

For now `MyTestRunner` will write the arguments / configuration in a temporary file,  then `External_Unit_Test.dll` will read the configuration from it.

Is there a better way to communicate between `MyTestRunner` and `External_Unit_Test.dll`?

The question is also asked [here on GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1297)

Answer (score 1):

As covered in various xUnit [issues](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/645), there is no specific facility of xUnit.net wrt this.

Normally such context is passed through Environment Variables (perhaps with a level of indirection by packing stuff up in a config file of some kind and then passing the path to that).

This lowest common denominator approach also works well with typical CI rigs.